# Estimote Eddystone stops scanning - javascript

Tags: estimote, eddystone

so I am using an Evothings example on eddystone scanning and for some reason after some time the app won't scan anymore.

Calling function startScan every 500 ms :

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Start tracking beacons!
     setInterval(function(){ startScan() }, 500);
}
```

startScan function:

```
function startScan() {
    // console.log("Startscan called"+new Date());
    // Called continuously when ranging beacons.
    evothings.eddystone.startScan(
        function(beacon)
        {
                console.log("Startscan called evo"+new Date());
                // Insert/update beacon table entry.
                beacon.timeStamp = Date.now();
                beacons[beacon.address] = beacon;
                domodalandstuff(); // this function opens a bootstrap modal to show some data
        },
        function(error)
        {
                console.log('Eddystone Scan error: ' + JSON.stringify(error)+" "+new Date());
        }
)};
```

After ~10 minutes I see this in my console:

- LOG: Startscan called evoMon Jan 16 2017 15:47:45 GMT+0100 (CET)
- LOG: Eddystone Scan error: "Scanning already in progress!" Mon Jan 16
  2017  15:47:45 GMT+0100 (CET)
- LOG: Eddystone Scan error: "Scanning already in progress!" Mon Jan 16
  2017 15:47:45 GMT+0100 (CET)

The app just stops calling startScan(), so of course my app won't find beacons anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is "Calling function startScan every 500 ms". Like this you start many scans at once.

You should call it only once. Your startScan function calls evothings.eddystone.startScan which **starts** and keep scanning until stopped. So you shall call `evothings.eddystone.startScan` only once and it will call your successCallback each time beacon is detected.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    startScan();
}
```

Note: You should call `evothings.eddystone.stopScan` somewhere.

Comment: Thanks I will try this and if it works I will mark it as the answer :).

Answer (score 0):

Yea very stuipid mistake thanks @Dietatko, it worked if you are wondering this is what I came up with:

```
     function checkmodalup() {
      if ($('#myModal').is(':visible')){
         evothings.eddystone.stopScan();
         isscanning = false;
      }
      else {
        if (isscanning === false) {
         evothings.eddystone.stopScan();
         startScan();
            isscanning = true;
        }
        else if (isscanning === true) {
            console.log("is already scanning");
        }
      }
}
```